# ¿Por que usan .default para leer info de un json?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo este archivo json:

```
{
"direccion": [
    "Carrera 52 # 91-66",
    "Medellín Colombia"
],
"email": "usuarioapellido@hotmail.com",
"sitioweb": "www.usuarioapellido.com",


"redsocial": [
    "www.instagram.com/usuarioapellido",
    "www.linkedin.com/uauarioapellido"
],
"correspondencia": [
    "Carrera 52 # 91-66",
    "Envigado Colombia"
],
"telefonos": [
    {
        "fijo": "+57 (4) 313-70-00"
    },
    {
        "cel": "(312) 313-44-77"
    }
]
```

}

y de vue tengo esto para leer la información que está en el json, donde desde la data lee el json para tenerlo disponible y luego en el html utilizo el .default que es lo que no entiendo

```
>  <template>   <div class="container-fluid">
>     <div class="row">
>       <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
>         <div class="container-fluid bg-white mt-2 ml-2">
>           <div class="font-weight-bold">
>             <h6>INFORMACIÓN DE LA EMPRESA</h6>
>           </div>
>           <div class="d-inline-block text-center pb-5">
>             <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Nombre</h6>
>             <p>Quipux S.A.S</p>
>             <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Fecha de creación</h6>
>             <p>1995/05/06</p>
>             <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Dirección</h6>
>             <div class="d-inline-block">
>                 <p>Carrera 43A No. 3 Sur-130</p>
>                 <p>Ed. Milla de Oro</p>
>                 <p>Distrito de negocios Torre 1</p>
>                 <p>Piso 12</p>
>             </div>
>             <div class="d-inline-block">
>                 {{ this.info.default.direccion[1] }}
>             </div>
>             <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Números de teléfono</h6>
>             <div class="d-inline-block">
>                 <p>Fijo</p>
>                 <p>{{ this.info.default.telefonos[0].fijo }}</p>
>                 <p>Fax</p>
>                 <p>{{ this.info.default.telefonos[1].cel }}</p>
>             </div>
>           </div>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>       <div class="col-12 col-lg-7"></div>
>     </div>   </div> </template>
> 
> <script> import * as InfoContacto from
> "@/jsonfiles/info-contacto.json";
> 
> export default {   name: "empresas",
> 
>   data() {
>     return {
>       info: InfoContacto,
>     };   }, }; </script>
```

---

Mi pregunta es por qué usan al importar el archivo json * as y el resto es la ruta, y también por qué cuando muestran la información json en el html usan **.default **, no se que relación tiene hacer esto

Por favor, ayúdame. no entiendo por qué usan de esta manera. Se los agradezco

Answer (score 0):

En JavaScript, cuando se hace una importación mediante el `import` con el asterisco `*`, es porque estás importando **todos** los objetos, variables, funciones, etc. que se están exportando en el archivo al que le estás haciendo el `from`.

El `as` hace referencia a la variable en donde se guardarán todas esas importaciones. En este caso, en el objeto `InfoContacto` deberías poder acceder a todo lo que se exporte en el archivo `info-contacto.json`.

¿Por qué no le haces un `console.log()` a esa variable para ver su contenido?

Después, el `default` tiene que ver con lo que se exporta. Lo que hace es limitar la cantidad de  objetos, variables, funciones, etc. a **uno solo**. Evitando así que se exporten varias cosas.

Te dejo estos dos artículos en donde encontrarás más información:

- [Importa el contenido de todo un módulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#importa_el_contenido_de_todo_un_m%C3%B3dulo.)
- [What is export default in JavaScript ?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-export-default-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=Default%20Exports%3A%20Default%20exports%20are,use%20any%20name%20to%20import.&text=Using%20Named%20and%20Default%20Exports,imported%20in%20the%20same%20file.)